# is there a way I could have a function in haskell to unwrap two monads and maybe produce the third one? like >>= for binary functions?

Tags: haskell

So essentially as far as i understand, using

```hs
mb_l :: Maybe L
l2mb_c :: L -> Maybe C
thing = mb_l >>= l2mb_c
```

in Haskell is equivalent to using

```rust
fn thing(mb_l: Option<l>, l2mb_c: fn(_: l) -> Option<c>) -> Option<c> {
    l2mb_c(mb_l?)
}
```

in rust.
But in rust I also can do something like

```rust
fn thing2(mb_a: Option<a>, mb_b: Option<b>, ab2mb_c: fn(_: a, _: b) -> Option<c>) 
-> Option<c> {
    ab2mb_c(mb_a?, mb_b?)
}
```

Is there a way I could do this in Haskell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have

```
mb_a :: Maybe A
mb_b :: Maybe B
ab2mb_c :: A -> B -> Maybe C
```

you can combine them as

```
thing = do
  a <- mb_a
  b <- mb_b
  ab2mb_c a b
```

or, using the applicative style

```
thing = join $ ab2mb_c <$> mb_a <*> mb_b
```

Comment: Maybe it’s worth mentioning the desugared monadic style too: `mb_a >>= \a -> mb_b >>= \b -> am2mb_c a b`. (Also, I’m not entirely sure I’d call your last example ‘applicative’ *per se*, given the use of `join`…)

Comment: So if i understand correctly, in the applicative style snippet, <*> is the first operation to be executed, and it builds a "bundle" through which ab2mb_c is applied (which is possible because <$> has very low binding strength), and afterwards join is applied to result of ab2mb_c? Why is the join there? I thought it essentially unwraps a nested monad?

Comment: @bradrn could you tell me if the desugared style you mention essentially builds a and b argument bundle unwrapping b only if a is some, and then call the function? If I'm wrong could you elaborate?

Comment: No, `<$>` is first; intuitively, it applies `ab2mb_c` to `mb_a` to get a `Maybe` value that wraps the resulting function; then `<*>` lets you apply a wrapped function to a wrapped value. More simply, you can use `Control.Applicative.liftA2` for this: `liftA2 ab2mb_c mb_a mb_b`.

Comment: @HerbalTea You mention the idea of an ‘argument bundle’ a couple of times; however, no such concept exists in Haskell. It is important to understand that a function application `f x y` is parsed as `(f x) y` — that is, first `f` is applied to `x` to produce a function, and then that function is applied to `y` to produce the final value (which may then itself be a function which you can apply to a further argument `z`, and so on and so forth). Then, `(f <$> x) <*> y` works similarly… (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) …first `f` is applied to the wrapped value `x` using `(<$>)` (also known as `fmap`), producing a wrapped value which can be applied to another wrapped argument `y`. (We need `join` because `f` itself returns a wrapped value here, so you end up with two layers of wrapping.) My own suggestion, `x >>= \x' -> y >>= \y' -> f x' y'` works in a slightly different way: we ‘unwrap’ (so to speak) the first argument followed by the second argument, then restore the wrapping by applying `f x' y'`.

Comment: @HerbalTea The cost common scenario is having `f :: a->b->c` and `ma :: m a`, `mb :: m b` in which case `f <$> ma <*> mb` gives a `m c` value. In your case, however, `f` returns `m c` at the end, so `f <$> ma <*> mb` gives `m (m c)` and we need `join`.

Comment: @bradrn, I actually knew that in Haskell you can apply arguments to a function one by one, bit since I was confused by join, and frankly am still confused by it. Why would adding an argument to a function return an instance of a maybe? I mean - if we have + as (Num a) => a -> a -> the. (1+) is (Num a) a -> a, right? So what do we get when we add one arg to f - is it Maybe(mb --> mc)?

Comment: @HerbalTea I don’t quite understand what you mean… if `f :: a -> b -> Maybe c` and `x :: a`, then `f :: b -> Maybe c`. Similarly, if `x' :: Maybe a`, then `f <$> x' :: Maybe (b -> Maybe c)` — `(<$>)` adds an extra layer of wrapping. This may be easier to understand with unary functions: if `g :: a -> b`, then `g x :: b` and `g <$> x' :: Maybe b`.